# Search for user with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

User's have accounts and can comment using a `Comment` Mongoose model. 
Is it possible to allow a user to enter a `username` in an text input and generate all user associated comments?

I've been trying to use `db.users.find({"name")` but I'm not sure how to pass a `username` from an input field to search. Any suggestions?

Thanks! The comment model is below. It connects each comment with a user.

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String

    }
})
```

Comment: Can you show us code and dbstructure as well?

Comment: What do you mean by `generate all user associated comments` ? you want to create a new record or you want to find record based o name?

Comment: Added the model above. Shrabanee I'm wanting anyone using the website to be able to look up users comments. So "User1" could search for "User2's" comments by typing in "User2" into an input on the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take the `user name` entered by another user from the `text box` and send it with **the request to back end**, something like `{uName : 'user2'}`.

Use the value from the object coming with the request and do find in your data base.

Something like below will be the backend code:-

```
var uName = req.params.uName

var cursor = db.users.find({username : uName.toString()});
```

Now `cursor` will give you record from `user2` from your data base.

Answer (score 0):

**Front-end**

> send your **GET** request with Query String to the Back-end API

```
<form method="get" action="/comments/user" >
   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
   <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**Back-end**

> write a API to deal with **GET** request and Mongoose Query

```
var app = express();

var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);


app.get('/comments/user', function (req, res) {

    var query=Comment.find();

    //get the Query String here
    var filter=req.params.username;

    if(filter.length>0){

      query.where({author.username:filter});

    }

    query.exec(function (error, comment) {
           //send the result back to front-end
            res.json({ Comment: comment });
    });
});
```